# Jena remove OntClass

Tags: java, jena, ontology

Currently I am using Jena to work around ontology file, but could not find a way to remove a class. I want do somthing like:

```
public static OntModel deleteClass(OntModel m,String ClassName,String Namespace)  throws    FileNotFoundException{  
OntClass rmClass     = m.remove(Namespace + ClassName);  
return m;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`OntClass` inherits from `OntResource`, which exposes the [`.remove()`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#remove%28%29) method (and [many others](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html)).

So your code would be:

```
OntModel m = .... ; // your model
OntClass c = m.getOntClass( NAMESPACE + className );
c.remove();
```

Two other minor points:

- If you're using a lot of static methods, consider whether you have the right abstractions in your code.  Static methods can be useful, but creating and manipulating objects should be your default way of writing good Java code
- It's generally better if you stick to the standard Java conventions. You used `Namespace` and `ClassName` variables - if these are variables they should start with a lower-case letter (`namespace`, `className`); if they're constants use all-caps (`NAMESPACE`, `CLASS_NAME`).